# Add custom field(s) in `package.json` while performing build operation in angular

Tags: angular, package.json

I have a working angular application with few dependencies in it. It's  **Package.json** is

```
{
  "name": "ngrx-poc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 4202",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
    "@lottiefiles/lottie-player": "^1.5.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^13.0.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "apexcharts": "^3.33.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "lottie-web": "^5.9.1",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.7.0",
    "ng-otp-input": "^1.8.5",
    "ngx-lottie": "^8.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.2.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}
```

Now, I want to add custom field in `package.json` named as  *build_version* ex

```
"build_version" : "2022-04-13T08:20:47.990Z"
```

This property should be added in package.json on build time. i.e. when I will use `ng build --prod`

Can I do this ? If  yes how ?

Comment: If we added it before hand in `package.json` then also it is  fine. but, in this case please provide a way to update the value of that property on runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried modifying the `package.json` using a [replace-in-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file).

But, it won't work with angular (or more specifically in browser) and the maintainer is also insisting the same.

https://github.com/adamreisnz/replace-in-file/issues/154#issue-1203080403

Hence, I have used this and worked perfectly for me.

https://gist.github.com/Mustafa-Omran/bb0810c9e51a1453de8c298b524b217e?permalink_comment_id=4131520#gistcomment-4131520